# Install dummy (null) driver for unsupported device

Tags: windows, usb, driver

We have a hardware device that presents as a composite USB device: MSC+CDC+HID+WebUSB. We don't want to support WebUSB for Windows 7 for a variety of reasons, but would like the device to install "successfully" and find drivers for all the USB interfaces it supplies, so that the user doesn't see the Windows notification *"Device driver software was not successfully installed"*.

On Windows 10, support for all devices is already built in. On Windows 7 we supply  a driver installer that provides CDC (`usbser`), and the others are built in. The `.inf` file for CDC matches the device's USB VID, PID, and a specific MI, e.g. `USB\VID_vvvv&PID_pppp&MI_00`. The WebUSB device is at `USB\VID_vvvv&PID_pppp&MI_04`.

I'd like to supply a dummy driver for `MI_04` so it installs successfully but does nothing. Is there a built-in dummy driver available in Windows 7, or some way to use some other built-in driver that will do nothing? Or is it easy to build a dummy driver to install for that interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the wrong search term. I wanted a "null" driver. Link here explains: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/installing-a-null-driver. A null device is recognized but not used and will not be started.

Based on the link above, I added something like this to my `.inf`:

```
[Devices]
...
"WebUSB device dummy = NullInstall, USB\VID_vvvv&PID_pppp&MI_04
...

[NullInstall]
; empty

[NullInstall.Services]
AddService = ,2    ; no value for the service name
```